# Magento 2 - Create Product Programmatically Url Key Can't Assign Multiple Store View

Tags: magento2

i have multiple store view, and i create product programmatically with **ProductInterfaceFactory**, product successfully insert, but when i changing store view in front end, product page result not found, because  table **url_rewrite** only has one row url store (store id 1). how to fix it ?

```
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setSku($data['sku']);
        //$product->setStoreIds(array("1,2")); not working
        //$product->setStoreId("2"); not working
        $product->setName($data['name']);
        $product->setDescription($data['description']);
        $product->setTypeId("simple");
        $product->setVisibility(4); //catalog & search
        $product->setPrice($data['price']);
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $product->setStockData(['qty' => 50, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
        $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a possible way forward is like below; mostly, the `setCopyFromView` is what seems to make this possible. I found this in the function `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save::copyToStore`. I admit I find this quite flawed as the name, description for instance are duplicated regardless if their value is different but hopefully that may push you to the next stage.

```
        $data['sku'] = 'sku123';
        $data['name'] = 'Product test 123';
        $data['description'] = 'Product description test 123';
        $data['price'] = 123;

        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($data['sku'], true, Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $product = $this->productFactory->create();
            $product->setSku($data['sku']);
        }

        //$product->setStoreIds(array("1,2")); not working
        //$product->setStoreId("2"); not working
        $product->setName($data['name']);
        $product->setDescription($data['description']);
        $product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
        $product->setVisibility(Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); //catalog & search
        $product->setPrice($data['price']);
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setStatus(Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $product->setStockData(['qty' => 50, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
        $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);

        $storeIds = [1, 2];
        foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
            $this->product->setStoreId(Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID)
                ->load($product->getId())
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setCopyFromView(true)
                ->save();
        }
```

Comment: not working. url_rewrite only have store_id 1,

Comment: You might want to reindex of course

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy Could you please help me to get all dashboard's link inside top link also? I have posted question.

Comment: I did read your question. you need to be more specific, is it sign out to go in my account sidebar you are after?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy  still can't, finally im using $item->setStoreId($storeId); $this->urlPersist->replace( $this->productUrlRewriteGenerator->generate($item)); on my collection product id,  but i don't know if this is right way

Comment: Are your stores assigned to same website?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy There are only sign out right now. I need all dashboard links there before sign out. How to do that?? please help me.

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy yes

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy Any Update?

Comment: Then that is your problem, you can only have one url per website

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy, no i mean,  when i create product from admin url request path in url_rewrite generate for all store view automatically, but when i create product from code programmatically, url request  path only generate for default store view. you can try on your local. eg : https://ibb.co/7XDX1Tz ,  https://ibb.co/D9bt8dx